# Are there Centreon plugins developed in languages other than Perl?

Tags: plugins, monitoring, centreon-api

I'm currently exploring Centreon, a monitoring software. I've noticed that most of its plugins are developed in Perl, but I'm looking for examples in other programming languages.

I'm not familiar with Perl and so far, I haven't come across any plugin in other languages.

Could anyone assist me?